# My IP Address is on 3 blacklists

Tags: email, blacklist

I noticed my email address (my email address is through a web host where I also host my website) was being bounced from one or more professional email subscriber lists.

Through MX Tools I see that my IP is on 3 blacklists -- while it seems my email server is "OK"

So the server techs tell me it concerns my internet provider.

My internet provider indicated it could be outdated equipment (I did have an old router).

So my internet provider upgraded our physical cable/internet connection and I upgraded the modem and router (equipment supplied by the internet provider).

While my IP Address did change (the last few numbers in the string) I see that my "new" IP Address is also on the same blacklists.

Could this blacklist issue have started with my email server... or is it my internet provider?

What is the best way to have your IP Address removed from a blacklist?

Any help or reference to resources is much appreciated!

Comment: It is unclear for me what you are doing. It is unclear how you deliver your mail. It is unclear what the error message specifically says - you only provide your interpretation of it. *"Through MX Tools I see that my IP is on 3 blacklists ...."* -  What do you mean with "my IP"? Usually mails are send using the mail server of the mail provider - and it is only relevant if this IP address (and not the IP address of your internet access) is on a black list.

Comment: My emails are bouncing. I'm told my IP Address is blacklisted. through my  web host, I use email - using the email server settings I send email through Mac Mail (TLS). Mx tools testing for email deliverability indicates the "from" field is my ip address (via internet provider); the "by" field is the email server ip. The email server ip isn't on a blacklist, my ip address via internet provider is on a blacklist. I'm trying to figure out what and how to fix it

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich  - I guess more info is needed, I'm not sure I helped w/ info in comment above. but if my email server isn't on a blacklist, then I shouldn't have email issues is that what you're indicating? (on some email lists I'm continually bounced using emails on the same server - in past my emails have indicated spam through other email clients or email software). sounds like my email server is, or was, the issue.

Comment: It is not even clear what kind of problems you have exactly, i.e. what the reason for the bounces is. Simply stating *"was being bounced"* does not provide any reason for the bounce.  Everything you provide are just interpretations and assumptions by *"the server techs"* (where it is also unknown what information they have) and by you.

Comment: I am trying to seek information as to why the email bounced, and the group sending the email newsletter has yet to get back to me. I should just wait then, right. In the meantime, if I am sending/receiving my email through my email application on my computer (Mac Mail), and not directly from the email server itself, would blacklisting of the ip address (of the ISP) have anything to do with my email being bounced?

Comment: *"would blacklisting of the ip address (of the ISP) have anything to do with my email being bounced?"* - how should we now? You don't provide the necessary details. In general it could be but it is unknown if it applies to your specific case.

Comment: Look at the email leaving your server. Is it a lot of spam? Are you running an Open Relay? Do you have a working *abuse* contact in your registration? Are you using encrypted server-to-server federated connections?

Comment: I believe I'll hire a technician to look into this for me, but I do appreciate your comments.

Comment: Try sending an email to check-auth@verifier.port25.com.  You'll get a return email back with a trove of information, including the IP or your mail server, any blacklists that it's on, whether mail servers hostname and IP forward and reverse properly, whether your SPF is setup correctly, and more.  From this, you'll be able to put your finger on any problems (or we can take a look if you append it to your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing is not clear, you say you are sending the mails from your webhost, then it has nothing to do with your ISP.

Check the IP address reported by Mxtoolbox carefully.

Mxtoolbox should probably provide links to the entities that have blacklisted your IP address. The reason for the blacklisting may be stated too.

You may be able to request an automatic or manual delisting, although this may be more difficult if you are not the owner of the IP address block in question.

I have been in the same situation. You can land in blacklists for no particular reason. Sometimes they like to case a wide net and blacklist whole IP ranges rather than go for the surgical approach and block individual IP addresses.

If your ISP/webhost has a rate of spam/abuse they deem high enough, then all customers could be affected the same.

Also, it is possible you are on a shared (not dedicated) server, meaning that your IP address is shared by other websites from other clients you don't even know about. The bad behavior of a single customer can affect other customers too.

Comment: Thank you. I have at least gotten the ip address issue cleared up I believe: so if i'm being bounced or listed as spam by other email clients or software, I should look more closely at issues with my email server. Is that it? And the email server techs told me it was ISP...

Comment: Anti spam (list) techniques also involve things like DKIM/DMARC/SPF and a proper certificate….